# How to get all sliced data from the entire file

Tags: javascript, html

I get the original code from here: [Using Javascript FileReader with huge files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17472313/using-javascript-filereader-with-huge-files)

But my purpose is different, the author wants to get just a part of the whole but I want them all.

I'm trying modify it with loop, mixed with this technique: [slice large file into chunks and upload using ajax and html5 FileReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20212851/slice-large-file-into-chunks-and-upload-using-ajax-and-html5-filereader)

All fails, is there anyway I can get what I want.

```
var getSource = function(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            if (e.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) {
                process(e.target.result);
            }
        };

        var part = file.slice(0, 1024*1024);
        reader.readAsBinaryString(part);
};

function process(data) {
    // data processes here
}
```

Thank you,

Comment: What about it fails? Whats the relevance of the code posted?

Comment: It does not repeat the process until completed. It stops after getting the getting the first data.

Comment: You're going to have to use a loop, in each iteration slice the required chunk and upload it.