# Upload csv file to Node.js server with fetch API

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, express, fetch

On my frontend application, I have a form where a user can upload a file. I want to upload this file to my Node.js backend using the `fetch` API.

### Frontend code

HTML:

```
<form id="forecast-form">
    <input type="file" id="csvFile" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const csv = e.target.csvFile.files[0];
    console.log(csv); // This actually logs the file object

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('csvFile', csv);

    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
    };

    fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/v1/forecast', options)
      .then((res) => res.text())
      .then((data) => console.log(data)); // output: {}
}
```

### Node.js + express code

```
create: async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const body = req.body;
        console.log(body); // output: {}

        res.status(201).send(body);
        next();
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
}
```

**But the only output I get**, both from the frontend and backend, is an empty object {}.

Edit:
I wouldn't say this question is a duplicate since the aforementioned question in mind is not specific to the fetch API, which this question is.

Comment: If you logs your "e", What do you have ?

Comment: @JonathanDelean I have the submit event. The handler should behave properly since I get the file when logging e.target.csvFile.files[0]

Comment: can you give us more details about the express configuration ? which body parser are you using ? do you use a middleware ?

Comment: Express `body-parser` doesn't parse `mutipart/form-data`. You can use something like multer [https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer] to parse files

Comment: Yes thank you @ranjan_purbey I just found out. And sorry tsamaya I should've specified that I used no middlewares

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After finding some information from this question [Sending a CSV file from browser to nodejs server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42087291/sending-a-csv-file-from-browser-to-nodejs-server)
I realised I couldn't just use vanilla req.body like I do for json data, instead I need to use some sort of middleware to handle the multipart/form-data content type.

So I used the [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) middleware

```
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });

router.post('/forecast', upload.single('csvFile'), forecast.create);
```

Then on POST, the file will be uploaded under uploads/ and per multer documentation:

// req.file is the `avatar` file

// req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any